# Header files C++, return bad type

Tags: c++, header-files

I created simple code in MVS2010 but it doesn't work.

There is just a class with header file and main.

Could you tell me what is wrong?

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Developer.h"


int main() {

    Developer xx("asd", "sfdasdf", "asdsa");
    std::cout << xx.Dev_ID;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Header:

```
class Developer {
public:
    char * Dev_ID;
    char * Dev_Name;
    char * ApplicationType;
    char * Name_Application;

public:
    Developer(char * name, char * appType, char * appName);
    void create();
    void edit();
    void remove();
};
```

Class:

```
#include "Developer.h"

Developer::Developer(char * name, char * appType, char * appName){}
void Developer::create(){}
void Developer::edit(){}
void Developer::remove(){}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a semi-colon after your `Developer` class.

Comment: -1: It is hard to answer your question when you don't explicitly state what's wrong (compiler error or unexpected output). Multiple code files make it hard to reproduce the problem, and the code obviously doesn't compile due to the `;` behind the include lines.

Comment: -1: for "it doesn't work" >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run my app it gives an unhandled exceptions and crashes...

Of course it does. Your constructor doesn't fill in any of the member variables. So `xx.Dev_ID` is undefined; it contains random garbage. When you attempt to `std::cout` random garbage, the program rightly crashes.

You probably intend to initialize `Dev_ID` to some value. You need to do that in the constructor. That's what the constructor is *for*: initializing member variables.

As Chethan stated, you need to look through some basic C++ books.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to add a semicolon ';' after the class definition.
2. The definition of member function should be of the form `returnType ClassName::FunctionName(args)`.

   ```
   void Developer::create(){}
   void Developer::edit(){}
   void Developer::remove(){}
   ```
3. Also, you don't need a semi color after the #include directives. I would suggest going through a C++ basics book and try out the examples to get a hold of the language!

Comment: ok, I've edited my code and my post but it still doesn't work. When I run my app it gives an unhandled exceptions and crashes...

Comment: @Whiteangel: because you have a whole bunch of totally uninitialised pointers in your class object and then you try to dereference one by streaming it to `std::cout`.